# Return pdf url as result of web api 2 query

Tags: pdf, url, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In web API project i have functionality like pass URL for all to view pdf,

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("upload/document")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetPdf()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + @"Documents\test.pdf");
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");


            return response;

        }
```

i want url like **http://localhost:54316/upload/document/test.pdf**
but should not get url and when i run in Postman it get's download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the mime type needed to NOT be a `octet-stream`. Supposedly, using the stream causes the browser to just download the file. I had to change the type `application/pdf`.
2. add a header that changed the `content-disposition` to `inline`. since the content-disposition was already being set to `attachment`.

> ```
> string mimeType = "application/pdf"
> Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
> ```

Comment: Thanks for replay, but can you more elaborate the answer?where to i change in my code.

Comment: just add a header `Content-Disposition: inline; filename.pdf`

Comment: but with this code , how to get url ?i want url as i mentioned in my question?

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage GetPdf(String file){             string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + @"Documents\"+file);}

Comment: If u what to dynamic pdf pass url="/upload/document/{dynamic}.pdf" in your api. So when the user click the link it will show the pdf instead of download.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by my self, Here is my code

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/test/urlVideo")]
public string urlVideo()
{
  string baseUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/uploads/videos/test.mp4";
            return baseUrl;
}
```

And it's work perfect.So i get

> http://hostname/uploads/documents/text.pdf